# How do I calculate an integral of $F$ where $F = \langle y,x^2\rangle$?

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, vectors, vector-analysis

[image]

[image]

I have to calculate the above integral and I'm not sure how to do it. First I find the curl of $\langle y,x^2\rangle$ and I get:

$$\langle0,0,2x-1\rangle$$

Therefore it's not conservative because it's not all $0$s and I can't solve the integral.

Is that right? I feel like that isn't right.

Comment: You have $F$ and you have $r(x,y)$. Just do line integral.

Comment: @MathLover Wait so curl is unnecessary? How would I do the line integral?

Comment: OK let me add some details

Comment: @MathLover thanks!

Comment: Please replace the images of text by actual text with formulas typeset using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to make your post accessible for users with screen readers and search engines. Consider reading [How to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question) to improve the quality of this and future posts.

Comment: Personally I would suggest avoiding using angled brackets and just use normal parenthesis instead as it might be confused with the inner product.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$y = 2 + \frac{x^2}{2} \,$ (from $(0,2)$ to $(2,4))$

Parametrize it using $x = t$, $y = \frac{t^2}{2} + 2$

So your points on the curve are given by $(t, \frac{t^2}{2} + 2)$. Starting point is at $t = 0$ and the end point is at $t = 2$.

Now vector field is $(y, x^2)$ or $ (\frac{t^2}{2} + 2, t^2)$.

$r'(t) = (1, t)$.

Now you can do a dot product for your line integral from $t = 0$ to $t = 2$

Comment: awesome thanks!

Comment: You are welcome! Just be careful on how you do line integral in $2D$ vs. surface integral in $3D$.

Answer (score 1):

You can parametrize the path using $r(x)=(x,2+\frac{x^2}{2}),\,x\in[0,2]$. Hence, $r'(x)=(1,x),\,F(r(x))=F(x,2+\frac{x^2}{2})=(2+\frac{x^2}{2},x^2)$, and then proceed by definition of the line integral.

Comment: Okay, so what defintion would I use? is that the dot product one?

Comment: Look for line integral for vector fields.